# removing ceiling fan and installing a light fixture

Tags: lighting

The ceiling fan I took down has a black wire, a white wire, a ground wire and a red wire.  On the light fixture I will install, I've got a black wire, a white wire and a ground wire.  Do I simply wire-nut the red?

Comment: Are there two switches or one?

Comment: Two switches on wall.  One for light, one for fan - which is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's not the fan that has that wiring config, that's the romex feeding the box; right?

The fan likely has a blue wire, or another of some color, which is used to independently switch the light kit. So, the short answer is yes but you'll have to figure out which wire in the box goes to which switch and cap off the one you don't want to use.

This will leave a "dead" switch somewhere if it was, and still is, wired for independent switching. If so, you can remove the switch and replace the cover with one that has a blank where the dead switch was.

Comment: Right.  On the light, one wire is silver in color; one is copper.  The "ceiling" has a black, white and a red wire.  Read somewhere to cap off the black; but now, silver & copper issue.

Comment: @user32560: Color is irrelevant unless the person knew the configuration, but it sounds like you figured the switching out and removed one. Also, there shouldn't be a copper/aluminum issue. If the light is new(er) it's probably tinned wire; no special treatment for that. If it's old and aluminum, you need a small amount of "no-ox". I think you could find some wire nuts with some inside already - never used them.

Comment: Light is old.  It's a Moe Light.  Will get wire nut with no ox.  Now, trying to decide how to hang the darn thing.  Wires are in a hole drilled in the ceiling joist.  No room to stuff light wires into ceiling.  Will wither cut a small section away or hang with a screw hook.

Comment: It's likely a tinned wire, not an aluminum one -- so no need for no-ox @user32560